# Run PM2 Docker with specific environment

Tags: node.js, docker, pm2

I have been trying to pass the environment to my PM2 process so that I can target `development` or `production`.

My `Dockerfile` is the following:

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2:latest
COPY dist dist/
COPY pm2.json .
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "start", "pm2.json"]
```

I have the following pm2.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "script": "dist/server.js",
  "instances": "1",
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "development"
  },
  "env_production" : {
    "NODE_ENV": "production"
  }
}
```

And I couldn't manage to get the environment set properly so when I access `process.env.NODE_ENV` I always get "none" back.

I have tried changing the CMD to:

`CMD ["pm2-runtime", "start", "pm2.json", "--env", "production"]` and no joy.

I have also tried to get the environment variable set in the dockerfile like this:

ENV `NODE_ENV=production` and that's not picked up either.

I have also checked the latest PM2 documentation and swapped the pm2.json with a ecosystem.config.js with pretty much the same structure but that hasn't work either.

What am I missing? I'm sure that has to be something really easy to fix but can't get it to work.

THanks

Comment: have you tried `CMD ["pm2-runtime", "pm2.json"]`?

Comment: Just tried and didn't work either

Comment: Does the command above start your node app?

Comment: Yes, the app is started however I'm doing console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV) and I get all the time "none" back

Comment: Probably `CMD ["NODE_ENV=production", "pm2-runtime", "start", "pm2.json"]`?

Comment: With that I got C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"NODE_ENV=production\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Answer (score 1):

`CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "ecosystem.config.js", "--env=production"]` is working for me.